# Java android surfaceview became null when i pass it to another class construct

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, surfaceview

I have 3 classes one of them is an activity.
Inside activity oncreate

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();    
MovementDetector detector = new MovementDetector(this, camera);
            if(detector == null)Log.d(null, "detector null in activity");
            MovementResult result = new MovementResult(this, detector);
```

Inside MovementResult

```
public class MovementResult extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder holder;
        MovementDetector detector;

        public MovementResult(Context context, MovementDetector detectorview) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            detectorview = detector;
            if(detector == null)Log.d(null, "detector null in constructor");
            if(detectorview == null)Log.d(null, "detectorview null in constructor");
        }
```

After a long and painful search (becouse i havent checked becouse i dont see the reason...) turned out in the class MovementResult detector is null. Both log shows up in the logcat that you can see in the constructor however the log in the activity dont shows.

So i have an object in an activity that is not null. Then i pass it to another ones constructor and it becomes null there. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

detectorview is the argument passed, detector is the null member.

It seems like you want to set detector to be detectorview, but instead you are setting (the passed) detectorview to be (the null) detector, which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: oops... Yes that not exactly what i wanted to do. :) works now thx.